# SP Administrator Toolkit for stress testing SP 2010?

Tags: performance

I'm looking for a simple way to execute stress tests on a new SP 2010 farm.

The [SP Administrator toolkit page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff823736.aspx) says that it an use SP **2007** logs to create the load test, for use in upgrade scenarios.

I'm not sure to understand the purpose of this toolkit, and especially, I'm wondering if I can use this toolkit to create from scratch load tests.
If not, what are my options ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate you can do performance testing against an entire farm - Read here for more: http://www.martinhatch.com/2010/09/forays-into-sharepoint-2010-performance.html

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own stress test application that creates sites, pages and list -uploads documents and so on. You could use PowerShell or the object model. Shouldn't be too much work to do.

Comment: not sure to understand... you are talking about creating an app (or script) that performs scenarios ??

Comment: moreover, writing myself such an application is not a good idea. tests load frameworks can manage actual user scenarios : roles, number of users per roles, scenarios with latency between clicks, requesting pages AND associated resources, etc. I don't have the pretension to be able to write such an application myself (actually, it will be more expansible than using something in place)

Comment: OK, if you have the need for a more complex tool (user scenarios, roles, etc) you surely wont do it yourself. Since I dont know the SP Admin Toolkit I can only point to Visual Studio Testing Tools (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385902(v=vs.90).aspx)